# how to setvalue in combobox from database in javafx

Tags: javafx

I have one combo in javaFX that is populated with categoryData

```
@FXML
private ComboBox<categoryData> comboCategory;
```

comboboxCategory suppose to fetch data from database when i clicked the edit button, but i get an error with this line

```
comboCategory.getSelectionModel().select(rs.getString("category"));
```

here is my error:

```
method selectionModel.select(int) is not applicable
string cannot be converted to int
method selectionModel.select(categoryData) is not applicacle
string cannot be converted to categoryData
```

please help me i am searching for this since yesterday but i got nothing. thank you for your response.

Comment: OBVIOUSLY you need to use a object with a type that matches the type parameter to specify a item to be selected. You need to find a suitable way to get the correct `categoryData` item given a string.

Answer (score 0):

I FOUND THE ANSWER OF MY QUESTION

```
Predicate<categoryData> matcher = data1 -> (data1.getCategory()).equals(rs.getString("category");
Optional<categoryData> opt = data.stream().filter(matcher).findAny();
comboCategory.setValue(opt.get());
```